# Product data in woo commerce from other table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Can I insert product data into other table rather than 'wp_postmeta' in woocommerce? and If so, how can i insert those data into cart?

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I have more than 3,00,000 products and these products are updating on daily basis, so I want separate table for these product but these should be stored in cart object when we add them into cart.

Comment: A lot of the way that WooCommerce deals with orders, products sales etc is linked to the post_id of the product - products are merely just another type of 'post' I would looking at the many hooks and filters that Woo have placed in areas related to updating and accessing product data. Is the cart the only place that WordPress really touches the product data? Or will there be a wp_post entry for each product? If that's the case, then you can just hook in to where Woo retrieves product metadata and swap in your own code linked to the external data storage